# codeigniter pagination url in different format

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I am getting codeigniter pagination url like

```
http://myapp.com/sample/2
```

But i want to get url like

```
http://myapp.com/sample?page=2
```

I already set `$_config['page_query_string']=True,`
but no use , can any one tell how to fix this issue

Comment: you can also make custom pagination function which display value according to query string so that you dont need to change default config setting

Comment: can you tell me how to use custom pagination?

Comment: to many library available in internet for example http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Comment: k. how to achieve this pagination in codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

his code is in php, in codeigniter should be identical.

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$path = explode("=", $url); 
$last = end($path);
```

the variable $ will represent the last page where you stand

Comment: I dint get, but when i set $_config['page_query_string']=TRUE, i am getting url like http://myapp.com/sample&page=2

Comment: if you are receiving the url, you'll have to cut the url in the "=" to fetch the id of the page, right?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

the pagination links will become something like

```
http://myapp.com/sample?&m=page&per_page=20
```